# print_r of json_decode is blank

Tags: php, json

I have a file data.json that looks like

```
{
"18.01": [{
        "name": "Title 1",
        "id": "0",
        "content": {
            "html": "This should be 18.01 video 1",
            "link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Dkm8Hteeh6M"
        },
    }, {
        "name": "test_video_2",
        "id": "1",
        "content": {
            "html": "This should be 18.01 video 2",
            "link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/KWafZrA5OBc"
        },
    }],
    "18.02": [{
        "name": "test_video_3",
        "id": "0",
        "content": {
            "html": "This should be 18.02 video 3",
            "link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/EMELKZhM2-g"
        },
    }, {
        "name": "test_video_4",
        "id": "1",
        "content": {
            "html": "This should be 18.02 video 4",
            "link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/TkWmK-cplV4"
        },
    }]
}
```

Then I have a php file in the same folder that looks like:

```
<?php

//Decode JSON
$json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.json'), TRUE);

//Print data
print_r($json_data);

?>
```

But when I load this php file in my browser I get a blank page. My php service is running (other php works fine), and if I print just the file that I'm loading that displays fine as a string.

Edit: If you're getting this error remember to validate your JSON unlike me...

Comment: Also a tip, when developing enable errors so you can avoid such mistakes.

Comment: That's not valid JSON according to [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: Whoops; that ')' got removed when I was copying. It's actually there in the code.

Comment: you also have trailing commas after the last elements of some lists/objects

Comment: You have invalid JSON. Try making it valid.

Comment: More debugging gives `Syntax error, malformed JSON`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: Have you tried using json-encode like below : json_decode(json_encode(file_get_contents('data.json')), TRUE);

Comment: That's badly-encoded JSON, you should fix whatever produced that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above JSON is syntactically wrong. The valid JSON is :

```
    {
  "18.01": [
    {
      "name": "Title 1",
      "id": "0",
      "content": {
        "html": "This should be 18.01 video 1",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/Dkm8Hteeh6M"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "test_video_2",
      "id": "1",
      "content": {
        "html": "This should be 18.01 video 2",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/KWafZrA5OBc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "18.02": [
    {
      "name": "test_video_3",
      "id": "0",
      "content": {
        "html": "This should be 18.02 video 3",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/EMELKZhM2-g"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "test_video_4",
      "id": "1",
      "content": {
        "html": "This should be 18.02 video 4",
        "link": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/TkWmK-cplV4"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

> Trailing commas are not allowed in a JSON, *like at line 8 in the JSON string mentioned with the question*

Furthermore, to validate JSON, you could use this [nice website](https://jsoneditoronline.org/)